# Почему обновляются данные во всех Map

Tags: java

Не могу понять, каким образом у меня обновляются данные во всех трех мапах?

```
public void updateMap(Map<String, WagonFinalInfo> map, String wagons, String rates, String tariffs) {
    List<WagonRateAndTariff> listRateAndTariff = PrepareDateForInsert.fillListForUpdate(wagons, rates, tariffs);
    Map<String, WagonFinalInfo> oldMap = new HashMap<>(map);
    Map<String, WagonFinalInfo> tempNewMap = new HashMap<>(map);
    logger.debug("listRateAndTariff: {}", listRateAndTariff);
    for (Map.Entry<String, WagonFinalInfo> _map: tempNewMap.entrySet()) {
        for (WagonRateAndTariff list : listRateAndTariff) {
            if (_map.getKey().equals(list.getNumberOfWagon())) {
                if (_map.getValue().getRate() != (Double) list.getRate()) {
                    _map.getValue().setRate(list.getRate());
                }
                if (_map.getValue().getTariff() != (Double) list.getTariff()) {
                    _map.getValue().setTariff(list.getTariff());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    newMapWagonFinalInfo.putAll(tempNewMap);
    logger.info("newMapWagonFinalInfo: {}, oldMap: {}", newMapWagonFinalInfo, oldMap);
    classHandlerInsertRateOrTariff.insertDate(newMapWagonFinalInfo, oldMap);
    calculateYield(newMapWagonFinalInfo);
}
```

Обновляют вроде как в `tempNewMap`, а на выходе получаю обновления и в `map` и в `oldMap`, что не должно быть. Каким образом это происходит-то?

Comment: Ну просто, когда вы создаете новую мапу на основе существующей new HashMap<>(map), то все элементы кладутся и в новую мапу тоже. Но это все те же элементы, а не их копии

Comment: да я и через for-each делал, когда put добавлял в новую, все равно.

Comment: Ну оно через for-each в конструкторе и происходит. Вы понимаете, что кладете ссылки на объекты, а не сами объекты? Таким образом у вас в трех мапах одни и те же объекты

Comment: понимаю, но у меня ступор щас возник, как тогда мне получить данные из map, положить их к newMap, и работать именно с newMap?

Comment: я и clone пробовал, результат тот же

Comment: @Владислав попробуйте в for-each сделать clone() каждому элементу.

Comment: @Tsyklop спасибо большое, я сделал немного по другому, я в for-each создаю отдельно новые объекты ключа и значения, а затем уже путом добавляю в мапу. Таким образом сработало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что коллекции хранят ссылки на объекты, а не сами объекты. Если вы создаёте два отображения

```
Map<String, SomeClass> first = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, SomeClass> second = new HashMap<>();
```

добавляете объект в первое

```
first.put('A', new SomeClass());
```

а потом "копируете" во второе

```
second.put('A', first.get('A'));
```

то объект в куче остаётся только один, а в отображение second добавляется ссылка на этот объект. Чтобы этого избежать нужно выполнить *глубокое копирование*, то есть создать в куче новый объект и перенести в него данные из старого. Хорошей практикой является возложение функции копирования объекта на него самого. Обычно это делается объявлением *конструктора копирования*:

```
class WagonFinalInfo {
    // Поля и другие конструкторы
    ...

    public WagonFinalInfo(WagonFinalInfo source) {
        setNumberOfWagons(source.getNumberOfWagons());
        // Копирование остальных данных
        ...
    }

    // Аксессоры и другие методы
    ...
}
```

И потом в том месте кода, где надо создать копию отображения

```
Map<String, WagonFinalInfo> newMap =
    oldMap.entrySet()
          .stream()
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, WagonFinalInfo::new));
```

Подозреваю, что в вашем случае стримы могут пригодиться не только для создания  глубокой копии, но и для сокращения всего многословного метода с квадратичным алгоритмом до пары строк с существенно меньшим потреблением памяти и циклов процессора.

Comment: Сергей, спасибо большое за развернутый ответ, очень полезная информация.

Comment: Что-то попробовал под себя сделать, не вышло(( После изменения в темповой мапе, меняются значения и в основной(( и new подчеркивает, пока не сделал конструктор public WagonFinalInfo(Map.Entry<String,WagonFinalInfo> source) {

Answer (score 0):

пришлось сделать вот так

```
for (Map.Entry<String, WagonFinalInfo> _map: oldMap.entrySet()) {
        String numberWagon = new String(_map.getKey());
        WagonFinalInfo wagonFinalInfo = new WagonFinalInfo(
                _map.getValue().getNumberOfWagon(),
                _map.getValue().getCountCircleDays(),
                _map.getValue().getDistanceEmpty(),
                _map.getValue().getCurrentNameOfStationOfWagon(),
                _map.getValue().getCurrentKeyOfStationOfWagon(),
                _map.getValue().getNameOfStationDepartureOfWagon(),
                _map.getValue().getKeyOfStationDepartureOfWagon(),
                _map.getValue().getRoute(),
                _map.getValue().getCargo(),
                _map.getValue().getCargoType());
        tempNewMap.put(numberWagon, wagonFinalInfo);
    }
```

Никогда не думал, что столкнусь с таким :) И то что скопировать мапу не так просто

Comment: Для чистоты кода вы можете воспользоваться конструктором копирования. Т.е. передавать в ваш конструктор объект WagonFinalInfo, а уже в конструкторе делать разбор полей, что облегчит ваш метод с бизнес-логикой